# jquery not performing the way correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I've got some jquery to show you first

```
$(function(){
    function darkBox(div){
        var w = (div.attr('width')) ? div.attr('width') : div.width();

        var h = (div.attr('height')) ? div.attr('height') : div.height();

        var box = $('<div></div>').addClass('darkCover');
        $('body').prepend(box);
        box.fadeTo('fast', 0.8);

        var contentBox = $('<div></div>').html(div.html());
        contentBox.addClass('darkContent');

        var x = $(window).width()/2;
        var y = $(window).height()/2;
        var startW = h-y/2;
        var startH = w-x/2;
        var endTop = y - h/2;
        var endLeft = x - w/2;

        contentBox.css("left", x+"px");
        contentBox.css("top", startW+"px");
        contentBox.css("z-index", "910");
        contentBox.css("width", w+"px");
        contentBox.css("height", h+"px");

        $('body').prepend(contentBox);
        // contentBox.fadeIn('slow')
        contentBox.animate({
            opacity: 1,
            width:w+"px",
            height:h+"px",
            top:endTop+"px",
            left:endLeft+"px"
        }, 1000, "easeOutExpo");

        box.click(function(){
            box.fadeOut();
            contentBox.fadeOut();
        });
    }

    $('.darkBox').each(function(){
        var div = $($(this).attr('href'));
        div.hide();
        $(this).click(function(){
            darkBox(div);
        });
    });
});
```

and my css is also below

```
.darkContent{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #333;
    font-family: arial;
}
.darkCover{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 900;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and html

```
<a href="#useThisDiv" class="btn blue btn-xs darkBox">Show Box</a>
<div id="useThisDiv" width="500" height="500">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I cant work out where the issue is but my issue is when I click on that anchor tag with the class `darkBox` it just redirect me to another page. It actually create that the `var box` div and within a second just disappears my current jquery is work fine without this one.. please help

if you can't sort out issue in this i just want to open a popup div every time user clicks a button the background should become slightly opaque and user can input data on that box.

Any idea?

Comment: What if you preventDefault() on anchor click?  $(this).click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();
            darkBox(div);
        });

Comment: @SSA it still does go to index page... dont know why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behaviour of the click event with `preventDefault`. Now your browser will be redirected to anchor #useThisDiv.

Update your code to:

```
$('.darkBox').each(function(){
    var div = $($(this).attr('href'));
    div.hide();
    $(this).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        darkBox(div);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, use a `data-` attribute instead of `href` to define this sort of extra functionality. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljujw6hn/1).

Comment: but that prevent this line of code `box.click(function(){ box.fadeOut();contentBox.fadeOut();});` cant get this disappear and that should not be the solution because i'm not asking it to go to any page just open a div resided on that page

Comment: thanks for your effort though i pressed up arrow for your effort but if you know any other way achieving this i'm happy to follow those instructions.

Comment: I'll update the Fiddle later, the click handler for removing the box is evoked immediately instead of on a second click.

Comment: Could you check? I've updated the Fiddle. You need to take care of memory leaks, cause this code is very leaky. Some reorganization would help. (but IMO this is out of the context of your question)

Comment: this works on fiddle great may i ask what was the issue please.. thanks @Anzeo :)

Comment: if you could guide me what should I ask i'm not a jquery developer so please advise me what to do get this error fixed... i'm learning in the process too

Comment: I moved `#useThisDiv` from the href to data-target and moved the click handler to remove the overlay right after the creation of the `box` variable. Probably has to do with how JavaScript hoists function and variable declarations up top, but as I said you'll need to check this code for memory leaks :). Glad to have helped and GL with learning jQuery.